# ORC writes much slower than Parquet in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am having a dataframe that contains below data, column test_data contain `WrappedArray[WrappedArray[String]]` type of data.

```
+----------+-------+--------+--------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|LOT_NUMBER|MACHINE|FACILITY|LOT_TYPE|           REC_DATE|           FILE_NAME|           TEST_DATA|
+----------+-------+--------+--------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  ZJ8281U6| GIMS01|   BE6|      SN|2019-01-22 00:28:57|201807182036_HJ82...|[[0.001E+00,1..|
+----------+-------+--------+--------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I tested write with format ORC & Parquet, orc much more slower takes 3 minutes but Parquet only takes 3 seconds to complete.

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).format("orc").save("/tmp/datalog/")
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).format("parquet").save("/tmp/datalog/")
```

So much of article state that orc have better performance than parquet, but i have no idea takes so much time to write.
Any expert knows what goes wrong? Or any advice for me?

Comment: what distribution of hadoop? Is it cloudera?